# How to implement mobile website stored different url in cache database?

Tags: hooks

When a user visit our front page of website, we want to add argument behind the url, such as http://domainname.com?mobile=true. 
Because we found that drupal cache system only stored same url one time in database, so if cache saved mobile site theme in database, a visitor may got wrong display of front page. So stored different url in cache database could solved this problem(Maybe).

We found that hook_boot() is called before cache working. So is there a method that add argument behind url?

This is what I implement store different cache in database.

```
  function newsyd_boot(){
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $is_mobile = newsyd_get_user_agent();

    $mobile_string = 'mobile=true';
    $is_contain = strpos($current_url,$mobile_string);
    if(!$is_contain && $is_mobile == 1){
        $http_pre = "http://";
        $destination_url = $http_pre.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $destination_url .= "?";
        $destination_url .= $mobile_string;
        //echo "<!--";
        //echo $destination_url;
        //echo "-->";
        header('Location:'.$destination_url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems there is no reponse